# How to find the recently modified rows in the table?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table A having columns `Family ID, Name, Addr`. How I can find recently modified rows in the table? Is that can be done without adding any more column in the table?

Comment: If you have the appropriate backup and transaction logs available, you can restore a copy of the database to a point in time.  Then compare that to the current database and Bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, SQL Server does not track when a row was added to a table or modified. You would need to do this by adding a column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.A ADD RowAdded DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Of course this will set all existing rows to now, so it will only work for new rows going forward. If you want modified time also, you can add an additional column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.A ADD RowChanged DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

And keep it up to date with a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.A_modified
ON dbo.A
FOR UPDATE 
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE A SET RowChanged = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    FROM dbo.A as A INNER JOIN inserted AS i
    ON A.ID = i.ID;
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not find these rows unless you are not also writing modification time (or timestamp)..

You can also add trigger that logs modified ID's, but that does not sound like better solution.

If you want to find data, that is modified by your DML statement you can use OUTPUT clause.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to add a 'lastUpdated` column.  Apart from that, there's no real easy way to achieve this.